# Complex Pixelbin API-request signature requirements: What am I doing wrong?

Tags: python, rest, post

The signature requirements to make an API request via Pixelbin are quite complicated, to say the least. The documentation I followed on this:

https://www.pixelbin.io/docs/api/upload-api/

https://www.pixelbin.io/docs/api/authentication/

https://www.pixelbin.io/docs/api/signature-generation/

```
import requests
import hashlib
import hmac
import base64
import datetime
import json
import pixelbin

# CORE STEP 1 = FILE UPLOAD
# DOCUMENTATION FOR THIS CORE STEP: https://www.pixelbin.io/docs/api/upload-api/, https://www.pixelbin.io/docs/api/authentication/, and https://www.pixelbin.io/docs/api/signature-generation/

# Step 1: Define the values
api_key = "{my_api_key_goes_here}"
request_method = "POST"
request_path = "/service/platform/assets/v1.0/upload/direct"
request_query = ""  # This is empty as we're not providing any query parameters in this case
body_hash = ""  # This is empty because Content-Type is multipart/form-data
headers = {
    "host": "api.pixelbin.io",
}
timestamp = datetime.datetime.utcnow().strftime("%Y%m%dT%H%M%SZ")  # Pixelbin timestamp format
headers["x-ebg-param"] = timestamp
header_keys = ";".join(headers.keys())

# Step 2: Create the string to be hashed
str_to_hash = f"{request_method}\n{request_path}\n{request_query}\n" + ''.join(f'{k}:{v}\n' for k, v in headers.items()) + f"\n{header_keys}\n{body_hash}"
# print(str_to_hash)
str_to_hash = str_to_hash.encode()

# Step 3: Hash the string using SHA-256
hashed_str = hashlib.sha256(str_to_hash).hexdigest()
# print(hashed_str)

# Step 4: Create the final string to be signed
str_to_sign = f"{timestamp}\n{hashed_str}"
print(str_to_sign)
str_to_sign = str_to_sign.encode()

# Step 5: Sign the string using HMAC SHA-256
signature_key = "1234567"
signature = hmac.new(signature_key.encode(), str_to_sign, digestmod=hashlib.sha256).hexdigest()

# Step 6: Prepend 'v1:' to the signature
pixelbin_signature = f"v1:{signature}"

# Step 7: Add the Pixelbin Signature and timestamp to the headers
headers["x-ebg-signature"] = pixelbin_signature
headers["x-ebg-param"] = base64.b64encode(headers["x-ebg-param"].encode()).decode()

print(headers["x-ebg-signature"])
print(headers["x-ebg-param"])

# Step 8: Encode the API key in base64
headers["Authorization"] = f"Bearer {base64.b64encode(api_key.encode()).decode()}"
print(headers["Authorization"])

# Step 9: Upload the file
file_path = r"C:\Users\anton\Pictures\My Folderpath\TESTING WORKFLOW AUTOMATION\my_test_image_1.png"  # Replace this with your actual file path
with open(file_path, 'rb') as f:
     files = {
         'file': f,
     }
    response = requests.post("https://api.pixelbin.io/service/platform/assets/v1.0/upload/direct", headers=headers, files=files)

# Step 10: Check the response
if response.status_code == 200:
    print("File uploaded successfully.")
else:
    print(f"Failed to upload file. Status code: {response.status_code}. Response: {response.text}")
```

I get a 401 error from this. Am I doing something wrong with the signature generation step that I'm missing?

Thanks!